# Merge columns in Tabularx Environment

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, columns, column-width, merge

I have the following tabularx environment.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}r@{\hskip 1mm}l@{\hskip 5mm}l@{}}
\end{tabularx}
```

My problem is that for some rows I don't have 3 columns but 2, so I need to merge the first two columns and still be able to populate the fhird column.

I tryed to use `\multicolumn{2}{l}{Multi-column}\\` but it doesn't work, since you end up filling in only the second column and nothing gets merged.

I absolutely need to use tabularx since first and second columns must auto-adapt to the longest element in the column, but I also need to have some rows where I can merge the columns.

Update with more code:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}r@{\hskip 1mm}l@{\hskip 5mm}l@{}}

  A column 1 row 1 & A column 2 row 1 & A column 3 row 1 \\
  & A column 2 row 2 & A column 3 row 3 \\

  \rule{0pt}{5mm}

  B column 1 row 1 & B column 2 row 1 & B column 3 row 1 \\
  & B column 2 row 2 & B column 3 row 2 \\

  \rule{0pt}{5mm}
  
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{this doesn't work} & {won't work}\\

\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your claim that "I absolutely need to use tabularx since [the] first and second columns must auto-adapt to the longest element in the column" seems odd, as you don't appear to be using the `X` column type in any of the three columns of the `tabularx` environment. Please clarify what you mean by "auto-adapt to the longest element in the column".

Comment: your tabularx is wrong, you have no X column so you should not use tabularx. It can do nothing useful with such a column specification `\multicolumn{2}{l}{Multi-column}` does span two columns in tabularx.

Comment: "I absolutely need to use tabularx since first and second columns must auto-adapt to the longest element in the column," tabularx does _nothing"  about the longest element, you want a standard tabular for that

Comment: Apparently what breaks `\multicolumn{2}{l}{Multi-column}` from working is `\rule{0pt}{5mm}` which I use to separate specific rows.

Comment: This is how my table looks: https://i.imgur.com/C3LsBAG.png First column is aligned to right, second to left and third to left. The width of each column is dynamic since it's based on the longest element in that column. I

Comment: sorry you have posted no code to give anyone a chance to guess your problem. Add an example in your question from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that reproduces the error you are asking about. naturally `l` column widths are dynamc but they are unrelated to `tabularx`.  a `\rule` would not stop `\multicolumn` working unless used incorrectly but without an example I can not guess what you have done wrong

Comment: I added the code so you can test for yourself. The last `\rule{0pt}{5mm}` breaks the `\multicolumn`. Also `\multicolumn` ignores the `@{}` that removes spacing at the edges of the table.

Comment: the `@{}` is part of the column spec so you should supply that to `\mulicolumn` and th rul is part of the cell content, despite your spacing with blank lines around it, so should be in the argument of `\multicolumn`

Comment: you could replace `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}` by `\begin{tabular}` `tabularx` can not work with `{@{}r@{\hskip 1mm}l@{\hskip 5mm}l@{}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140315/discussion-between-cholmugod-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,    % new
            tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}  % new
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}   % new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} R@{\hskip 1mm}L L @{}}

A column 1 row 1    & A column 2 row 1  & A column 3 row 1   \\
                    & A column 2 row 2  & A column 3 row 3   \\
    \addlinespace
B column 1 row 1    & B column 2 row 1  & B column 3 row 1   \\
                    & B column 2 row 2  & B column 3 row 2   \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{l}{this work as expected}
                                        &  last column      \\
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note (let me repeat what other already tell you in above comments):

- In `tabularx` table at least one column had to be of `X` type.
- For increase vertical distance between selected rows is better to use of `\addlinespace` of `booktabs` package.
- For `multicolumn` cell is not clear, if it will contain only one line (short) text or it should enable automatic break of text in a several lines. In above MWE is considered the former case.

Comment: So if I shouldn't use tabularx, what should I use then to achieve the same result?

Comment: It works anyway using `\addlinespace` while I don't understand why you used the ragged stuff since those change the spacing of the columns.  Using my table definitivo everything is fine.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that text in first column doesn't start from the left edge of the page, but somewhat in the middle instead.